# Gradle - substitute dependency when not existing

Tags: gradle

If a dependency version doesn't exist in a repository, I want to be able to provide a substitute version.

Reading through the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html), this seems possible:

> This can be useful if a certain dependency version is broken and
>   should not be used, where a dependency resolve rule causes this
>   version to be replaced with a known good version. One example of a
>   broken module is one that declares a dependency on a library that
>   cannot be found in any of the public repositories.

I can see how to switch a dependency, but I can't work out how to first check if the dependency doesn't exist.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems, it's not about detecting broken dependencies, but about changing the broken one if it ever used. The only way you can find it out, is a build fault. It's not a common case, to rely on the fact dependecy is broken. So every time, then dependency doesn't exist anymore, it's ok to change your build script.anymore, it's ok to change your build script.